# How to save changes properly in code-first without navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have problem to design to split config without navigation property. it makes each work/transaction call SaveChanges twice. I dont know it effect performance or not. I see alot tutorial only call SaveChanges one time only. Is there a new ways entityframework to design code-first without navigation property?

Program

```
using (ApplicationDbContext context = new())
{
    using (var contextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var account = new Account 
        {
            AccountId = "stack237762"
        };

        context.Accounts.Add(account);

        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Users.Add(new User 
        {
            Username = "Admin",
            Password = "PassAdmin",
            AccountId = account.Id
        });

        context.SaveChanges();
        
        contextTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Entities

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
}
    
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AccountId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Context

```
public class UserEntityConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey("Id");

        builder.Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(t => t.Username)
            .IsRequired();
        
        builder.Property(t => t.Password)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne<Account>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.AccountId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a single save without a property such as `public Account Account { get; set; }` in the user class?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis yeah, without navigation property. its not possible? is bassically navigation auto call SaveChanges in background?

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt but I don't think you can do a single `SaveChanges` call without a navigation property. You have to somehow assign a User to an Account. In order to do it you either need to know the AccountId which means that you need to save the account first so that from the DB you can get the new ID that got assigned or you have to use the navigation property I have above to do it in a single `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis i trys with mix navigation and fluent. it gives me error.

Comment: What kind of error are you talking about? I can send you an example.